# How to select records from one table where values from all the records in a column of second table match any of the multiple columns of first table?

Tags: mysql

There is a table (table A) with columns parent1, parent2 ..., parent7. All these columns contain user_id values, showing user_id values of 7 generations. Now there is another table (table B) which contains a column of some user_id values. I want to select all the records from table A which contain any of the user_db values from table B in any of table A's parent columns. How do I do that?

Comment: Do you know about table joins?

Comment: Yes I do. But the problem is how do I join them when the matching values are spread accross multiple columns in table B? You need a single column to define JOIN ON, right?

Comment: No, you can join on multiple columns.

Comment: That seems to work perfetctly! Thanks.

Comment: You should post what you got as an answer so others can benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table joins is the way to do this.

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON (
  a.parent1=b.user_id
  OR a.parent2=b.user_id
  OR a.parent3=b.user_id
  OR a.parent4=b.user_id
  OR a.parent5=b.user_id
  OR a.parent6=b.user_id
  OR a.parent7=b.user_id
)
```